# Is a semisimple conjugacy class closed?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be any algebraic subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n$ over an algebraically closed field of any characteristic.

If $s$ is a semisimple element of $G$, can the $G$-conjugacy class of $s$ fail to be closed in $G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No---it's always closed. See 18.2 in Humphreys, *Linear Algebraic Groups*.

Comment: Is it still true when the field is not algebraically closed?